# How to use annotation based configuration to configure multiple buckets in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

In the Couchbase documentation the below is given as an example to configure the environment. What would be done for having more than one bucket ?

```html
@Configuration
public class Config extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "beer-sample";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple buckets in `2.0.x` branch, the way it currently works is that you have to instantiate a second `Bucket` bean and the associated `CouchbaseTemplate` (that's the hardest part):

```
//we want all User objects to be stored in a second bucket
//let's define the bucket reference...
@Bean
public Bucket userBucket() {
  return couchbaseCluster().openBucket("users", "");
}

//... then the template (inspired by couchbaseTemplate() method)...
@Bean
public CouchbaseTemplate userTemplate() {
  CouchbaseTemplate template = new CouchbaseTemplate(
    couchbaseClusterInfo(), //reuse the default bean
     userBucket(), //the bucket is non-default
    mappingCouchbaseConverter(), translationService() //default beans here as well
  );
  template.setDefaultConsistency(getDefaultConsistency());
  return template;
}
```

After that, you'll probably also want some of your repositories to use this second template (and bucket). There's currently an implementation for that as well (`RepositoryOperationsMapping`), but it's probably going to change a bit until upcoming **`2.0.0-RC`** so I won't go into details there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why do I need a Bucket bean if I already have a template? Isn't the purpose of the template to encapsulate the Bucket and wrap its operations? Also I could get the Bucket with getCouchbaseBucket method -- [api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.0.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/CouchbaseTemplate.html#getCouchbaseBucket--) -- if I need it, unless there is anything spcific for the mappings you mention that require having a Bucket bean. Thanks again

Comment: Well if you want to store into different buckets, the template offers an abstraction over bucket operations but it relies on the bucket, so there's no way around creating a reference to one

Comment: @SimonBaslé I'm using  **spring.data.couchbase** `3.0.6.RELEASE` and when i try to add multiple buckets its throwing password incorrect exception. Could you please help me with that.